# How is the Twin Primes Constant useful? What value does it provide over Brun's Constant?

Tags: prime-numbers, constants, twin-primes

The [Twin Primes Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TwinPrimesConstant.html) is:

$$\prod_{p > 2 \text{ and a prime }}\left(1 - \frac{1}{(p-1)^2}\right) = 0.6601618158\ldots$$

It appears that in this case $p$ does not have to be a prime.  But if that's true, why is it called the twin primes constant?

[Brun's constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrunsConstant.html) is:

$$\frac{1}{3} + \sum_{p>3 \text{ and } p,p+2  \text{ are primes }}\left(\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p+2}\right) = 1.902160540\ldots$$

Brun's constant seems straight forward to me.  The sum of the reciprocal of twin primes converges so there is no proof in the sum of reciprocals for the infinitude of twin primes.

I am not clear what to make of the twin primes constant.  What value does it give?  How did Merten use it when he came up with it?  Why is it interesting?

Comment: Do you mean, "It appears that in this case $p$ does not have to be a **twin** prime"?

Comment: One small point: As written, the first term of the second sum is $\dfrac 1 3 + \dfrac 1 5\vphantom{\dfrac{\displaystyle\int}{\displaystyle\int}}$ and the second is $\dfrac 15 + \dfrac 17\vphantom{\dfrac{\displaystyle\int}{\displaystyle\int}}$, so $\dfrac 15\vphantom{\dfrac{\displaystyle\int}{\displaystyle\int}}$ appears twice.  Is that standard and is that as it should be? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: For one thing, it appears in conjectured asymptotic estimate of number of twin primes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime#First_Hardy.E2.80.93Littlewood_conjecture

Comment: @Vectomaut, yes, my question is about $p$.  I am not clear if $p$ needs to be a twin prime or not.  Based on reading the Math World article, I was unclear.

Comment: @Michael, very good point.  I will fix it.

Comment: @Wojowu, thanks very much!  That's the answer that I was looking for and also clarification if it is based on all prime $p$ or just the twin primes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be called the "twin prime constant" because it comes up a lot in theorems and conjectures about twin primes. For example, from the [relevant MathWorld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TwinPrimes.html):

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

This constant appears in the conjectured asymptotic estimate on the number of twin primes below a given size, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime#First_Hardy.E2.80.93Littlewood_conjecture). It's also noteworthy that this constant wasn't just taken out of thin air, this can be actually derieved heuristically via Cramer's random model.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The twin prime constant is relevant to the *asymptotic density* of the twin primes.

Answer (score 2):

@LarryFreeman I think you will better understand the meaning of the twin primes constant, if you write it in the form
$$ 
C _2 = \frac {{  \prod_\limits{p \geqslant 3 }} \left( 1 -\frac {2}{ p} \right)} {{  \prod_\limits{p \geqslant 3 }} \left( 1 - \frac 1 p \right)^2}  
 = { \prod \limits_{p \geqslant 3 }} \, \frac{p(p-2)}{(p-1)^2}. 
$$